# VS2010 FTP Publish from mutliple machines

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ftp, publishing

I *think* this issue is caused by publishing from multiple machines.

When I click publish I get the following in the output/build window

```
Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
Publishing folder /...

========== Build: 6 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I.e. its not iterating the folders to be published - When it works 'Publishing folder /...' lists every folder in the project.

obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp is correctly built with publishable content - I end up FTP'ing it manually to publish.

This seems to start once I publish a project from more than one machine (i.e. more than one developer, or one dev multiple machines, shared code via git, more than one publisher) but that might be conincidence.

Any ideas what I can do to fix/reset this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.  I was working on a web app on one machine and it deployed fine. When i was on the road, I pulled the source code and it wouldn't publish. I noticed that I forgot to check-in the Properties\PublishProfiles folder to SVN so I had to recreate it.  I believe the problem is with the Profile.pubxml.user file.  It needs to contain all of the files in the  tag.  I just created a new profile and then copied the pubxml.user to a file that matched the broken profile.

Comment: I've also got the .user files excluded from git ... Thanks Jim